# How do oracle date time work?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I have following where condition in query. What the time is between T1 and T2 means it **includes or excludes** the boundary. Also between T1 and T1 means what?I am confused as both returns result.

```
DATETIME BETWEEN TO_DATE(D1-T1,'MM-dd-yyyy HH24:MI:SS' )  AND TO_DATE(D1-T2,'MM-dd-yyyy HH24:MI:SS' )

DATETIME BETWEEN TO_DATE(D1-T1,'MM-dd-yyyy HH24:MI:SS' )  AND TO_DATE(D1-T1,'MM-dd-yyyy HH24:MI:SS' )
```

Comment: The TO_DATEs make no sense to me, they seem to only introduce implicit type conversion (a bad thing).

Comment: @kubanczyk what do you suggest

Comment: What are the types (definitions) of "DATETIME", "D1", "T1", "T2"?

Answer (score 3):

`BETWEEN` is inclusive. From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions011.htm#SQLRF52164):

> And the value of
>
> ```
> expr1 BETWEEN expr2 AND expr3
> ```
>
> is the value of the boolean expression:
>
> ```
> expr2 <= expr1 AND expr1 <= expr3
> ```

So your first clause will match exactly `T1`, exactly `T2`, and anything in between. Your second clause will match exactly `T1`, i.e. any rows where `DATETIME` is exactly `T1`.